# Starting a proof with \paragraph

Tags: sectioning, amsthm, sections-paragraphs

I would like to break a proof into paragraphs, but I don't seem to be able to start a proof with a paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\paragraph{This bit in bold.} Now this part of the proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

It seems to be fine if I insert text before the \paragraph, but otherwise I get the following error:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

What is the simplest way to start a proof with a paragraph?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `\paragraph` is a sectioning command, like `\section`. If you just want to divide material into paragraphs, use a blank line to separate them: is that what you are after?

Comment: You can also put a `~` before the first instance of `\paragraph`

Comment: @JosephWright: I'm after the bold formatting that paragraph gives to the supplied text (I've updated my example to make that clearer).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: thanks. Also just discovered that adding \item before \paragraph has the same effect, although I don't know why.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes But that will only make the `H` bold, as it's the section-like argument which `\paragraph` grabs.

Comment: @JosephWright  I'm not familiar with `proof` environment, so I didn't know how it's supposed to look.  Sorry if my answer is more smoke than light.  I was commenting only on how to spoof things like `\\\`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add an \item or ~ before \paragraph. For example:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\item 
\paragraph{This bit in bold.} Now this part of the proof.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The spacing with this solution is a bit odd, but that does the trick.

Comment: You can also use ~ instead of \item

Comment: @Nubok Thanks. Just noticed that Steven B. Segletes also mentioned that trick a few years ago. Tweaked the title of the answer to bring attention to that alternative.

Answer (score 6):

I think the best way is to define a new environment, let's say `breakproof`, that acts like `proof` but starts with a new line after the word "Proof".

So you can write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakproof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces\item
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{breakproof}
    \textbf{This bit in bold.}
    \newline
    Now this part of the proof.
  \end{breakproof}
\end{document}
```

and the result is:

[image]

Otherwise, you can redefine the `proof` environment (bad practice, in my opinion) and use it as before (the result is the same):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces\item
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{proof}
    \textbf{This bit in bold.}
    \newline
    Now this part of the proof.
  \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. What are the advantages of this over just adding \item at the beginning of the proof? (This seems to have a similar effect, in that the proof then starts with a newline after "Proof.".)

Comment: Only aesthetics, for me. But you may have a different opinion, and just use `\item` inside the normal `proof` :-)

Comment: Ok, I accepted your answer, but I also added my own answer below.

Comment: Karl, looks like you are a mathematician ;)

Comment: @HarishKumar These are the same words they told me when I got graduated. Are you sure you weren't there at that time? You know, my memory is going away...

Comment: @karlkoeller Hope you don't mind, after a few days' experimentation, I changed my mind and accepted my own answer below. I'm finding it more convenient, and it's consistent with an idiom I use in theorem environments to force them to start with a newline.

Comment: @Roly, I don't mind, but at least upvote mine...

Comment: @karlkoeller Done :)