# Align element (tikzmark) with top of the current line instead of baseline

Tags: vertical-alignment

I'm trying to raise a `\tikzmark` in order to align it with the top of the current line (for instance to draw a line something like that):

[image]

For now I use `\raisebox{4mm}{\tikzmark{Hello0}}`, but I don't know how to do it without hardcoding the height of the line (the actual height could be smaller or larger depending on the letters/equations used in the line). Any idea how to do? (If you also know how to lower it to make sure it aligns with the depth I'd also be interested)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Space wanted (line should be added)}

\noindent Hello my dear.\\
\noindent Goood \rule[-5mm]{1cm}{15mm}

\section{Raising: how to choose the good value to ensure it aligns with top of the line?}

\noindent Hello my dear.

\noindent \raisebox{4mm}{\tikzmark{Hello0}}Goood \rule[-5mm]{1cm}{15mm}\tikzmark{Bye0}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw (pic cs:Hello0) -- ({pic cs:Bye0}-|{pic cs:Hello0});


\section{Using par: adds space between lines}

\noindent Hello my dear.

\noindent \tikzmark{Hello1}\par \noindent Goood \rule[-5mm]{1cm}{15mm}\tikzmark{Bye1}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw (pic cs:Hello1) -- ({pic cs:Bye1}-|{pic cs:Hello1});

\section{Baseline does not help}

\noindent Hello my dear.

\noindent \tikzmark{Hello4} Goood \rule[-5mm]{1cm}{15mm} \tikzmark{Bye4}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw ([yshift=\baselineskip]pic cs:Hello4) -- ({pic cs:Bye4}-|{pic cs:Hello4});

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

To clarify, the proposed answer does not solve my problem, I really want the line to adapt to the content (and the edit also does not work in my case because I can't box my content as it may span multiple pages, see my question/answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622930/116348) for more details). For instance I **don't** want this result:

[image]

but I'd like something like (of course without hardcoding the values).

[image]

I updated my MWE accordingly.

**EDIT**

I tried the `\hrule height0pt` proposition: it's quite nice, but it shifts the tikz mark on the right, not sure why (to copy at the end of the previous MWE):

[image]

```
\section{Hrule: shift the bar on the right}

\noindent Hello my dear.

\noindent \hrule height0pt\tikzmark{Hello5}\hrule height0pt Goood \rule[-5mm]{1cm}{15mm} \hrule height0pt\tikzmark{Bye5}\hrule height0pt
\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw (pic cs:Hello5) -- ({pic cs:Bye5}-|{pic cs:Hello5});
```

**EDIT**

It seems that we got two solutions: one based on reseting `\baselineskip`-like variables, and one using `\hrule height0pt`. It turns out that both of these approaches are complementary. For instance, `\hrule height0pt` gives the best result when I tried to insert a tikzmark right after a `\qed` symbol, but this same approach gives very strange alignment sometimes (I tried to use strut, but then the alignments are much too big):

[image]

while `\baselineskip` gives better results in that case:

[image]

The file I'm using (see the `\addZeroWidthLine` function):

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532948/robustly-add-a-border-to-the-left-of-a-text-spanning-several-pages
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{environ}

\def\subproofsDefaultShift{5mm}
% Shift towards the center of the line
%\def\subproofsDefaultFirstPointYShift{.3em} %% Better results when using baselineskip
\def\subproofsDefaultFirstPointYShift{0em} %% Better results when using `\hrule height0pt`
\def\subproofsDefaultSecondPointYShift{0em}

\tikzset{
  /subproofs/defaultStyle/.style={
    black!30!white,
    line width=.4pt,
    transform canvas={xshift=-\subproofsDefaultShift/2-.5pt},
  }
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Deal with drawings and marking.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Warning: tikz does not like ExplSyntax since it removes spaces
\def\addTikzmarkAndPagesInfo#1{%
  \tikzmark{beginTikzmark#1}%
  \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \coordinate (pageInfoNWOf#1) at (current page text area.north west);%
  \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \coordinate (pageInfoSEOf#1) at (current page text area.south east);%
}


\def\drawLinesOfTikzmarkSamePage#1{%
  \tikz[remember picture, overlay]%
  \draw[/subproofs/defaultStyle] ([yshift=-\subproofsDefaultFirstPointYShift]pic cs:beginTikzmark#1) to ([yshift=\subproofsDefaultSecondPointYShift]{{pic cs:endTikzmark#1}-|{pic cs:beginTikzmark#1}});%
}

\def\drawLinesOfTikzmarkStart#1{%
  \tikz[remember picture, overlay]%
  \draw[/subproofs/defaultStyle] ([yshift=-\subproofsDefaultFirstPointYShift]pic cs:beginTikzmark#1) to ({pic cs:beginTikzmark#1}|-{current page text area.south west});%
}

\def\drawLinesOfTikzmarkMiddle#1{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[/subproofs/defaultStyle] %
  let%
    \p1=(pic cs:beginTikzmark#1),%
    \p2=(pageInfoNWOf#1),%
    \p3=(current page text area.north west),%
    \p4=(current page text area.south east) in%
    (\x1-\x2+\x3,\y3) to (\x1-\x2+\x3,\y4);%
}

\def\drawLinesOfTikzmarkEnd#1{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[/subproofs/defaultStyle] %
  let%
    \p1=(pic cs:beginTikzmark#1),%
    \p2=(pageInfoNWOf#1),%
    \p3=(current page text area.north west),%
    \p4=(current page text area.south east),%
    \p5=([yshift=\subproofsDefaultSecondPointYShift]pic cs:endTikzmark#1) in %
    (\x1-\x2+\x3,\y3) to (\x1-\x2+\x3,\y5);%
}

\makeatletter
% \checkmarkpage{label}{if before}{if same page}{if after}
% Apply different codes if we are on a page before, the current page,
\newcommand{\checkmarkpage}[4]% #1 = tikzmark label, #2 = less, #3 = equal, #4 = greater
{\@ifundefined{save@pt@#1}{#2}{%
  \edef\markid{\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname}%
  \edef\markpage{\csname save@pg@\markid\endcsname}%
  \ifnum\thepage<\markpage\relax #2%
  \else
    \ifnum\thepage=\markpage\relax #3%
    \else #4%
    \fi
  \fi}%
}
\makeatother

%%% Starts expl3 syntax https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf
%%% For the list of modules and everything http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf
%%% (this also provides a quickstart at the beginning)
%%% For functions https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492794/how-to-define-two-expl3-functions-with-the-same-base-name-and-different-signatur
%%% This code is certainly not an example of LaTeX programming as it's the first time I use expl3...
\ExplSyntaxOn

% l=local, name, type. Note that this is only convention, it could be named "\foo" instead.
% clist are list separated by commas.
% To remove stuff https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5754/delete-an-element-from-a-comma-delimited-list
\seq_new:N\l_ListOfLinesToDraw_seq{}

\newcounter{nextMarkId}

% Inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528774/excess-vertical-space-in-vdots/528775#528775
% See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622881/align-element-tikzmark-with-top-of-the-current-line-instead-of-baseline/622936#622936
% TODO: Read also https://fr.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/Boxes_and_Glue%3A_A_Brief%2C_but_Visual%2C_Introduction_Using_LuaTeX

\newlength{\oldbaselineskip}
\newlength{\oldlineskip}
\newlength{\oldlineskiplimit}

%%%% Uncomment to have the "baselinemode" (and comment next definition)
% \long\def\addZeroWidthLine#1{%
%   \oldbaselineskip=\baselineskip%
%   \oldlineskip=\lineskip%
%   \oldlineskiplimit=\lineskiplimit%
%   \baselineskip=0pt%
%   \lineskip=0pt%
%   \lineskiplimit=0pt%
%   \noindent#1\par\nobreak%
%   \baselineskip=\oldbaselineskip%
%   \lineskip=\oldlineskip%
%   \lineskiplimit=\oldlineskiplimit%
% }

%%%% Uncomment to have the "hrule" version:
\long\def\addZeroWidthLine#1{%
  \hrule height0pt\noindent#1\hrule height0pt%
}


\NewEnviron{subproof}{%
  \edef\thisMarkId{\thenextMarkId}% Temporary variable to use at the end.
  \seq_gput_right:NV \l_ListOfLinesToDraw_seq \thisMarkId % Add it to the list
  \begin{adjustwidth}{\subproofsDefaultShift}{0cm}%
    \dealWithOneLine:V{\thisMarkId}% Draw the line for the current one.
    \addZeroWidthLine{\addTikzmarkAndPagesInfo{\thenextMarkId}}%
    \stepcounter{nextMarkId}%
    % Ensures a group is inserted around the BODY
    { \noindent \BODY \par\nobreak}% nobreak is used to ensure the tikzmark is not pushed on a new page.
    \addZeroWidthLine{\tikzmark{endTikzmark\thisMarkId}}\nopagebreak%
  \end{adjustwidth}%
}%

\NewEnviron{linedproof}{%
  \edef\thisMarkId{\thenextMarkId}% Temporary variable to use at the end.
  \seq_gput_right:NV \l_ListOfLinesToDraw_seq \thisMarkId % Add it to the list
  \begin{proof}\phantom{x}% Not sure why, using ~ does not work.
    \begin{adjustwidth}{\subproofsDefaultShift}{0cm}%
      \dealWithOneLine:V{\thisMarkId}% Draw the line for the current one.
      \addZeroWidthLine{\addTikzmarkAndPagesInfo{\thenextMarkId}}%
      \stepcounter{nextMarkId}%
      % Ensures a group is inserted around the BODY
      { \noindent \BODY }% nobreak is used to ensure the tikzmark is not pushed on a new page.
      % \hrule height0pt also "fake" a zero-width line.
    \qedhere\hrule height0pt\tikzmark{endTikzmark\thisMarkId}\end{adjustwidth}%%
  \end{proof}

}%


%% Create a new function (see http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf page 14)

\cs_new:Nn \dealWithOneLine:n{
  \checkmarkpage{beginTikzmark#1}{%
    %%%%%%%%%% We have not yet seen the beginTikzMark... Don't care.
  }{ %%%%%%%%%% We are on the page of the start.
    \checkmarkpage{endTikzmark#1}%
    {%%%%%%%%%% The end is later
      \drawLinesOfTikzmarkStart{#1}%
      %\printList:N{} Size is \seq_count:N \l_ListOfLinesToDraw_seq%
    }%
    {%%%%%%%%%% The end is on the same page
      \drawLinesOfTikzmarkSamePage{#1}%
      %% We can remove the item from the list so that we don't process it anymore.
      \seq_gremove_all:Nn \l_ListOfLinesToDraw_seq {#1}%
      %\printList:N{} Size is \seq_count:N \l_ListOfLinesToDraw_seq%
    }{% The end was on a previous page... impossible
    }%
  }{ %%%%%%%%%% The start point is on a previous page
    \checkmarkpage{endTikzmark#1}%
    {%%%%%%%%%% The end is later
      \drawLinesOfTikzmarkMiddle{#1}%
      %\printList:N{} Size is \seq_count:N \l_ListOfLinesToDraw_seq%
    }%
    {%%%%%%%%%% The end is on the same page
      \drawLinesOfTikzmarkEnd{#1}%
      %% We can remove the item from the list so that we don't process it anymore.
      \seq_gremove_all:Nn \l_ListOfLinesToDraw_seq {#1}%
      %\printList:N{} Size is \seq_count:N \l_ListOfLinesToDraw_seq%
    }{%%%%%%%%%% The end has already been seen... I don't care
    }%
  }%
}

% defines \dealWithOneLine:V that expands its argument
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \dealWithOneLine:n { V }

%% Create a new function (see http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf page 14)
\cs_new:Nn \dealWithAllLines:N {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_ListOfLinesToDraw_seq {
    \dealWithOneLine:n{##1}
  }
}
%% Create a new function (see http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf page 14)
\cs_new:Nn \printList:N {
  [
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_ListOfLinesToDraw_seq {
    ##1,
  }
  ]
}

\AddEverypageHook{\dealWithAllLines:N{}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}


% \begin{subproof}
%   ABC
% \end{subproof}

\begin{linedproof}~% Use '~' to ensure  the subproof starts on a new line.
  % See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122954/starting-a-proof-with-paragraph
  %  \begin{subproof}%
    We prove now that $1+1+1 = 3$. First we will prove that $1+1+1=3$:
    \begin{subproof}%
      In order to prove that $1+1+1=3$, we first prove that $1+1=2$.
      \begin{subproof}%
        By definition $2 = 1+1$.
      \end{subproof}%
      But we can show that $1+1+1=2+1$.
      \begin{subproof}%
        Indeed, by associativity of the addition, we know that
        \begin{align}
          1+1+1=(1+1)+1\label{eq:abc}
        \end{align}
        But we saw above that $1+1=2$ so $1+1+1=2+1$
      \end{subproof}%
      It is now possible to see that $1+1+1=3$
      \begin{subproof}%
        We can use now Eq.~\ref{eq:abc} and the definition of $3$:
        \[1+1+1=2+1=3\]
      \end{subproof}%
      As you can see, the spacing issues are now solved. See \texttt{\subproofsDefaultFirstPointYShift} to move more or less the first point on the y axis (to ensure it's not too close to the above line). It defaults to \texttt{0.3em}.
      \begin{subproof}
        Also the line adapts to height and depth \rule[-1cm]{2cm}{3cm}.
      \end{subproof}%
      \lipsum[1-5]
      Bla bla bla bla blaBla bla bla bla blaBla bla bla bla blaBla bla bla bla blaBla bla bla bla blaBla bla bla biblobi blabla blabla Bla bla bla bla blaBla bla bla bla blaBla bla bla\qedhere
    \end{subproof}%

%    bla bla bla blaBla bla bla bla blaBla bla bla bla bla
%    bla bla bla blaBla bla bla bla blaBla bla bla bla blabla bla bla blaBla

%  Which concludes the proofWhich concludes the proofWhich concludes the proofWhich Which concludes the proof %Which concludes the proofWhich concludes the proofWhich concludes the proofWhich the proof.
\end{linedproof}

Hello

\begin{subproof}
  Coucou
\end{subproof}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, provide an sketch, what you expect form pictures? If image is above/below a line with `\tikzmark{<name>}` you need to reserve space for it. It is drawn as `overlay` , i.e. above its background.

Comment: You could use `\tikzmarknode` which knows the dimensions of the node that gets created.

Comment: You can use the option `yshift=\baselineskip` to reach the baseline of the line above, if this is what you want.

Comment: @Zarko Well the first picture I draw is the one I expect, except that I don't want to hardcode the content. See the edit I made to see how the text should adapt to images...

Comment: ABC: I'm note sure to see how it would help here. The text is not inside the picture but outside (it may even span multiple pages, so I don't want to include all the text into a tikz node). Maybe you could provide an example if I misunderstood something?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Well `\baselineskip` does not change if the text is smaller/higher. I tried for instance to put an image (see my edit) and the line is not updated accordingly.

Comment: Feels like you're asking for something similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100922/86, which isn't very hopeful.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thanks for this (not very encouraging) link. However, I guess it must somehow be possible to proceed in a different way, because mdframe seems to be able to do something like that to draw the frame around the text. I was thinking, would it be possible to put the `\tikzmark` alone in a line with zero height right before the text, and add a kind of `\newline` without any space to put the content right below? I guess it may involve some `\vbox` stuff but I'm not yet very good with that.

Comment: If you can put your text in a box then all is fine, I believe this is how `mdframe` works.  Then you can measure everything before the box is typeset.  But it felt like you didn't want to do this - you wanted to mark a point and the height/depth of the line that that point was on without affecting how TeX was laying out the text.  If there is a way to add a tikzmark at a set point of every line then I can see a way to do it, but I don't know if such is possible.

Comment: Try `\hrule height0pt \tikzmark{Bye0}\hrule height0pt`.  I like to think of `\hrule height0pt` as a horizontal strut.  It acts sort of like `\par`  but does not add any space below the previous line (not even `\lineskip`).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Hum, this seems to be interesting (and it seems to be slightly less buggy than manually adding `\par` and resetting all spaces)... however I do have one issue since it seems to have a non-zero width: the tikzmark is shifter on the right.

Comment: I found a solution, see my edit. It fixes the bug I had in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622930/116348

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need, you could maybe use one of these approaches:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\newbox\charbox
\setbox\charbox\vbox{\hbox{Gg}}

\noindent \tikzmark{Hello0}Goood

\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw[thick, red] ([yshift=\ht\charbox]pic cs:Hello0) -- (pic cs:Hello0);

\noindent \tikzmark{Hello1}goood

\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw[thick, red] ([yshift=-\dp\charbox]pic cs:Hello1) -- (pic cs:Hello1);

\noindent Goood \\
\tikzmark{Hello2}Goood

\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw[thick, red] ([yshift=\baselineskip]pic cs:Hello2) -- (pic cs:Hello2);

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could do something like:

```
\noindent\tikzmark{Hello0}\\[-\baselineskip]
\tikzmark{Bye0}Ggoood \rule{1cm}{15mm}

\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw[thick, red] ([yshift=\baselineskip]pic cs:Hello0) -- (pic cs:Bye0);
```

The `\tikzmark` is essentially placed in the line before, then a `\newline` is added and the following stuff is shifted upwards by `\baselineskip`. Since this line is empty, you can then use `yshift=\baselineskip` to adjust the `\tikzmark` to the correct position.

This approach is not absolutely accurate, though, and it would not consider the depth. Still, it would consider the height of the line regardless of its contents:

[image]

---

A more general approach would probably be to place everything that you want to measure in a box first of which you can easily get its height and depth. Of course, this again would *not* place the `tikzmark` at the top, but you can still calculate the height and depth.

I don't know whether such an approach is very reasonable, though, especially for your concrete use case. It seems to me that it would be better to use other tools such as `tcolorbox` etc. for such stuff since they provide a stable framework for boxing stuff.

Also, depending on what you want to achieve in the end, the code below can surely be optimised.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}

\newcommand{\boxify}[1]{%
\newbox\boxbox\setbox\boxbox\vbox{#1}#1%
}

\begin{document}

\boxify{\noindent\tikzmark{Hello0}Goood}

\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw[thick, red] ([yshift=\ht\boxbox]pic cs:Hello0) -- ([yshift=-\dp\boxbox]pic cs:Hello0);

\boxify{\noindent\tikzmark{Hello1}Goood \rule[-5mm]{1cm}{15mm}}

\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw[thick, red] ([yshift=\ht\boxbox]pic cs:Hello1) -- ([yshift=-\dp\boxbox]pic cs:Hello1);

\boxify{\noindent Hello \\ 
\tikzmark{Hello2}Goood 
$x^2 = \frac{x^6}{x^3}$}

\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw[thick, red] ([yshift=\ht\boxbox]pic cs:Hello2) -- ([yshift=-\dp\boxbox]pic cs:Hello2);

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue is that this is close to hardcoded height: it will not adapt depending on the height of the content. For instance if I put an image with a large height the line will not go height enough.

Comment: This is, of course, true.

Comment: Good that we agree, but the problem is still unsolved :-P

Comment: It was not clear to me that you had such cases in mind. Sorry.

Comment: Oh no problems ^^ Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Thanks for your edit, it's better (+1)but unfortunately in my case I can't "box" things to know their height because they may span multiple pages (for more details, see my answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622930/116348). And tcolorbox can't be used as well because they don't support nesting of box properly (see this same question for more details) But I was thinking, would it make sense to put the `\tikzmark` alone on a line of zero width before and after? That way it would be placed right above the text and right below. The only issue is that I don't know how to create such things.

Comment: I added a last idea, which places the `\tikzmark` in the line before and then shifts the line upwards at the linebreak. Since there is nothing in this line, you know its height exactly and you can therefore safely use `yshift=\baselineskip` here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. So I tried to use a similar idea, but using `vbox` like in this answer to obtain zero-height lines https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528774/excess-vertical-space-in-vdots/528775#528775 and the result is quite accurate and handles both depth and height (only one or two pixels too much space below the "y", not sure why). I'll try to play a bit to see if it works in my more initial problem, and check how robust it is.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small function to reset all length, and use it like that (I used it successfully on multiple pages). I'm not sure if it's the best method, but it seems to do the job.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Space wanted (line should be added)}

\noindent Hello my dear.

\noindent Goood \rule[-5mm]{1cm}{15mm}

\section{Raising: how to choose the good value to ensure it aligns with top of the line?}

\newlength{\oldbaselineskip}
\newlength{\oldlineskip}
\newlength{\oldlineskiplimit}

\long\def\addZeroWidthLine#1{%
  \oldbaselineskip=\baselineskip%
  \oldlineskip=\lineskip%
  \oldlineskiplimit=\lineskiplimit%
  \baselineskip=0pt%
  \lineskip=0pt%
  \lineskiplimit=0pt%
  \noindent#1\par%
  \baselineskip=\oldbaselineskip%
  \lineskip=\oldlineskip%
  \lineskiplimit=\oldlineskiplimit%
}

\noindent Hello my dear.

\noindent \addZeroWidthLine{\tikzmark{Hello}} \noindent Goood \rule[-5mm]{1cm}{15mm} \par\addZeroWidthLine{\tikzmark{Bye}}

\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw (pic cs:Hello) -- ({pic cs:Bye}-|{pic cs:Hello});

\end{document}
```

**Older solution that actually failed with multiple pages:**

Inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528774/excess-vertical-space-in-vdots/528775#528775) I got this version which handles both height and depth:

[image]

The spacing seems to be exactly the same as the one without the line...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Space wanted (line should be added)}

\noindent Hello my dear.

\noindent Goood \rule[-5mm]{1cm}{15mm}

\section{Raising: how to choose the good value to ensure it aligns with top of the line?}

\noindent Hello my dear.

% Inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528774/excess-vertical-space-in-vdots/528775#528775
% See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622881/align-element-tikzmark-with-top-of-the-current-line-instead-of-baseline/622936#622936
% TODO: Read also https://fr.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/Boxes_and_Glue%3A_A_Brief%2C_but_Visual%2C_Introduction_Using_LuaTeX
\vbox{% Save oldbaselineskip
  \newlength{\oldbaselineskip}\oldbaselineskip=\baselineskip%
  \newlength{\oldlineskip}\oldlineskip=\lineskip%
  \newlength{\oldlineskiplimit}\oldlineskiplimit=\lineskiplimit%
  % Set baselineskip to zero to have zero space b
  \baselineskip=0pt%
  \lineskip=0pt%
  \lineskiplimit=0pt%
  \hbox{}% The hbox creates a zero-height box
  \hbox{% Actual content... but first reset the baselinkeskip
    {%
      \baselineskip=\oldbaselineskip%
      \lineskip=\oldlineskip%
      \lineskiplimit=\oldlineskiplimit%
      % Actual content
      \vbox{\noindent Goood \rule[-5mm]{1cm}{15mm}}%
    }}%
  \hbox{\tikzmark{Bye0}}}
%\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw (pic cs:Hello0) -- ({pic cs:Bye0}-|{pic cs:Hello0});

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `\hrule` acts like `\par`, you need `\noindent` after (if you care about the horizontal position).  Ending the previous line with a `\strut` obviates the need for `\vskip\lineskip`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Raising: how to choose the good value to ensure it aligns with top of the line?}

\noindent Hello my dear.\strut
\hrule height0pt \noindent\tikzmark{Bye0}\hrule height0pt
\noindent Goood \rule[-5mm]{1cm}{15mm}
\hrule height0pt \noindent\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\draw[red] (0,0) -- (pic cs:Bye0);}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I've been playing with it: sometimes it gives better results compared to my solution with baselineskip (like to put a qed on the appropriate line), but otherwise it gives strange alignements (sometimes too big, sometimes too small, see my edit), so for now I'm using both solutions depending on the context. Any idea how to make this preserve the alignment? I tried to use `\strut` as you did, but then the alignments are too big then.

Comment: `\vskip\lineskip` works if the previous line has descenders (gypqj).

Comment: I tried to replace `\strut` with `\vskip\lineskip` but I get the same result (also, what is gupqj?)

Comment: Ah, so it means that there is no generic solution to preserve the spacing irrespective of the content of the lines with this method?

Comment: It depends on what you want.  Normally a large rule will be placed `\lineskip` below the bottom of the previous line (not the baseline), whether or not it has descenders.   `\vskip\lineskip` reproduces this behavior.  `\strut` is used to emulate `\baselineskip` placement (`\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox=\baselineskip`).  You might also try `\strut\vspace{-1pt}` as a compromise.